# How to use OnMouseLeftButtonDown on WPF for C++

Tags: c++, wpf, uwp, click

I'm doing a demo project on Windows Presentation Foundation with C++, and I'm trying to invoke a callback function when the user clicks the mouse anywhere on the screen.

I just have an empty main page:

```
public ref class MainPage sealed
{
    public:
        MainPage();
};
```

I know that I must override OnMouseLeftButtonDown(). However I can't find a sample code anywhere, especially on [Microsoft's page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.onmouseleftbuttondown?view=net-5.0) about it. In particular, I can't find how to import MouseButtonEventArgs on C++.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: "*I must override OnMouseLeftButtonDown()*" - not really, You would usually attach a handler method for the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.

Comment: Oh. So how would I do that? There's no sample code either on Microsoft Docs' page about the MouseLeftButtonDown event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the problem was that my project was configured for UWP, not WPF. Silly me...

Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Try this to hook up the event handler:

```
this->MouseLeftButtonDown += gcnew MouseButtonEventHandler(this, &TheEventHandler);
```

The `MouseButtonEventArgs` class is in the `System.Windows.Input` namespace:

```
using namespace System.Windows.Input;
```

Comment: That code is also not compatible with UWP, so it wouldn't have worked either.

Comment: Your question is tagged WPF and not UWP.